# Convert text with HTML character encoding to database characterset

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Our application receives data from various sources. Some of these contain HTML character makeup instead of regular characters. So instead of string "â" we receive string "&#226;".

How can we convert "&#226;" to a character in the database character set using SQL/PLSQL?

Our database is 10GR2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unescape_reference and excape_reference I believe is what you're looking for

UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE('hello < å')
This returns 'hello <'||chr(229).

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_i18n.htm#i998992

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I'm looking for. I don't think I would have found this on my own.

Comment: I was worried I couldn't find the 10GR2 link :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CHR() function to convert an ascii character number to a character representation.

```
SELECT chr(226)
  FROM dual;
```

> ```
> CHR(226)
> --------
> â
> ```

For more information see: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/chr.php

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks, see my comment at redcayuga's answer

Answer (score 0):

one solution

```
 replace(your_test, '&#226;', chr(226))
```

but you'd have to nest many replace functions, one for each entity you need to replace. This might be very slow if you have to replace many.

You can wrote your own function, seqrching for the ampersand and replacing when found.

Have you searched the Oracle Supplied Packages manual? I know they have a function that does the opposite for a few entities.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I was aware of the chr function. But parsing all strings is a bit cumbersome and that's why I asked this question here.

Answer (score 0):

to convert a column in oracle which contains HTML items to plain text, you could use:

`trim(regexp_replace(UTL_I18N.unescape_reference(column_name), '<[^>]+>'))`

It will replace HTML character as above stated but will also remove HTML tags en remove leading and trailing spaces.

I hope it will help someone.